# will cardio compromise mass if I'm in a caloric surplus?

Tags: training

I am aware that it's not black and white simple. 
If I consume enough (90%clean) calories, will cardio still compromise mass? Or is a deficit the main cannibalistic factor?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Surplus calorie has nothing to do with cardio; it has everything to do with mass though :).

Answer (score 5):

It all comes down to calories really (clean or not). If you eat more than you spend, you will gain. If you eat less than you spend, you will loose mass.

You can eat all the healthy or "clean" food you want but if you eat too much of it, the surplus of calories is there and you will gain mass (fat if you don't do weight training).

So, if you are in surplus of calories despite your cardio, you will still gain.

If you are doing weight training and want to "bulk up", including cardio is a good idea anyways, you just need to increase your calorie intake slightly to compensate.